# operator '< ' cannot be applied to operands of type 'system.windows.forms.datetimepicker' and 'system.datetime'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to run validation on my datetimepicker to make it so that you cannot select a date before today's date but keep getting the error above. I'm new to c# so still learning but this has me very confused. Below is my code any any help is appreciated.

```
if (dtpTravelDate < DateTime.Now)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Date Selected Cannot be Before Today's Date");
}
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: You don't want the datepicker *control*, you want it's *Value* (or whatever the name is of the property)

Comment: Try with `dtpTravelDate.Value`

Comment: What does this have to do with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use it's [`.Value` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value) of your object to compare it, not itself.

```
if (dtpTravelDate.Value < DateTime.Now)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Date Selected Cannot be Before Today's Date");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
if (dtpTravelDate.Value < DateTime.Now)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Date Selected Cannot be Before Today's Date");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (dtpTravelDate.Value < DateTime.Now)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Date Selected Cannot be Before Today's Date");
    }
```